# ajax jquery search form in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my form:

```
<form id="submitsearch" action="Classes/system/main/searchresult.php" method="POST">
Search by <span style="font-size:15px;">(developer, specialization, profession,major)</span>
    <input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" />
    in
    <select style="text-align:center;" name="countrysearch" id="countrylist">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">None</option>
        <option value="1">USA</option>
    </select>
<input style="margin-left:25px;" id="submitSearch" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

and this is the Ajax jquery code:

```
    $("#submitSearch").click(function(){

    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'Classes/requests/search.php', data:$('#submitsearch').serialize(), cache: false, success: function(response) {
        $('#submitsearch').find('#pagePanel').html(response);

});
```

Why isn't it working ? The php file is returning the correct result normaly.

But i want it to load inside another div with an id "pagePanel" without reloading, using ajax.

Any help ? I'm new to Ajax.

Edit:

```
    $("#submitbutton").click(function(){

    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'Classes/system/main/searchresult.php', data:$('#submitsearch').serialize(), cache: false, success: function(response) {
        $('#pagePanel').html(response);

}})});
```

This worked out with me.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What *exactly* is not working? What errors are you getting in the error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a input of type `submit`, it will, guess what :), submit the form, and therefore reload the page. Turn it into:

```
<input style="margin-left:25px;" id="submitSearch" type="button" value="Search"/>
```

Then make sure you actually *have* a `pagePanel` element in your html.

And now a couple of suggestions:

1. don't id your form `#submitsearch` and the button as `#submitSearch`... confusion may arise
2. you can use AJAX's `.load()` instead of `.ajax()` to get directly the result in the DIV:

So:

```
$("#pagePanel").load('Classes/requests/search.php', {$('#submitsearch').serialize()});
```

Comment: don't id your form #submitsearch and the button as #submitSearch... confusion may arise. I didnt pay attention just changed it and tried your way but didnt work.

Comment: LEt's break it down: leaving aside the suggestions, does the <input type="button"> thing work in first place?

Comment: It worked now after changing the type to button, the ither problem was the path :P i left my old path rather than changing it.

Comment: If you change from a `submit` to a `button`, you lose the browser's understanding of the button's connection to the rest of the form. Just as a simple example, this means you can't press the Enter key to run your search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ajax in the form submition you'll need to cancel it.

```
$("#submitSearch").click(function(event){
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'Classes/requests/search.php', data:$('#submitsearch').serialize(), cache: false, success: function(response) {
        $('#pagePanel').html(response);
    });  
    event.preventDefault();//prevents submitting of the form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to stop the default form submittal. return `false` in the submit handler to stop default.  Just use the ID of the element without using find() to insert data into. The elemnt you are trying to find doesn't appear in your html though within the form where your code suggests it should be

```
$("#submitSearch").click(function(){

    $.ajax({type:'POST',
           url: 'Classes/requests/search.php', 
           data:$('#submitsearch').serialize(),
           cache: false, 
           success: function(response) {
                 $('#pagePanel').html(response);
            }
    })

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

After pushing the `submit` button, the default behaviour is to submit the form and indeed go to the action URL you provided to your form. Now, you want to prevent that behaviour. This means, you'll have to look at the `onsubmit` event of the form, and prevent the actual submission. jQuery has a [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to do this.

In your case, all you'll have to do is add the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitsearch").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });        
});
```

And [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/uHm5k/) is a jsFiddle to demonstrate it.

You can obviously do the same thing to your submit button, just add the `e` variable as the argument to your `click` event and use `e.preventDefault()` to cancel the actual submit (but you can still perfectly do the AJAX request).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing a few closing parenthesis and curly brackets. Be sure to run your dev tools in your browser to check console for errors like that. I normally don't use $.ajax...I usually use $.post, but using what you have so far, I would rewrite to something closer to:

```
$("#submitsearch").submit(function(){

    var submitData = $(this).serialize();    
    $.ajax(
        {
            type:'POST', 
            url: 'Classes/requests/search.php', 
            data: submitData, 
            cache: false, 
            success: function(response) {
                $('#pagePanel').html(response);
            }
        }
    );
    return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending back loads of HTML to the page, you could just send results in form of a set of JSON objects and then dynamically create the HTML based on the results, this means a lot less data being sent back to the browser which is quicker and more efficient.